# Cannot find module XYZ

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, electron

I know this problem has been submitted endless times but even after browsing through X questions and possible solutions this error still remains.

I have a file called `tournament.js` in the directory modules. `tournament.js` requires `model.js` which resides in the exact same directory. The structure is the following:

```
app/
  modules/
    model.js
    tournament.js
```

tournament.js looks like:

```
const Model = require('./model');

class Tournament extends Model {

  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  static create() {

  }
}
```

Even WebStorm says the path in `require()` is correct but my console still says: `Uncaught Error: Cannot find module './model'`

What am I missing?

Edit: I'm using Node v6.4.0 and Electron v1.4.15

Comment: have you tried `const Model = require('./model.js');` ??

Comment: Whenever this happens to me, I always add a `console.log(__dirname)` directly before the failing `require(...)` just to make the folder name is correct. More often than not, I'm working in the *wrong folder*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay @adelphus gave me the correct hint. I outputted the path with `console.log(__dirname)` and it was not what I expected: Yes, I have been in the wrong path, because I thought the relative path `require()` takes is the one relative to the file I am currently working in (which was the tournament.js) and this is not the case.

Instead `require()` takes the path relative from the app root which in this case was `./app/models/model.js`

Comment: Node does take `./` to mean the same as the current file's directory – "[*`circle.js` must be in the same directory as `foo.js` for `require('./circle')` to find it.*](https://nodejs.org/dist/v6.4.0/docs/api/modules.html#modules_file_modules)

Comment: Well it doesn't work for me. Maybe I should also note, that I'm using gulp and my automated tasks copies my code from `./src` into the folder `./build` but with the same folder structure (so `src` and `build` are identical from the structure). Then gulp runs `electron build/main.js`. `__dirname` then outputs a complete different path. Instead of being it `./build/app/models` it's `./build`. I don't know why.